# Accessing single variables from a query

Tags: php

I can get two values, an easting and a northing, from the database and format them like this: 123456 | 123456. However, I would also like to pass the easting to the $easting variable and the northing to the $northing variable so I can use them individually. How do I do that?

Here's my code so far.

```
<section id="aside" class="clearfix">
<section id="recipientcase">
<h3>Site Area: <?php if(isset($_POST['site_area'])){echo $_POST['site_area'];} ?></h3>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <select id="Area_select" name="site_area" tabindex="1" class="selmenu" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="site_area">--- Area ---</option>
        <?php
        // postgresql database connection
        $area_array = pg_query($db_connection, "
            SELECT area_easting, area_northing
            FROM excavation.contexts 
            GROUP BY area_easting, area_northing
            ORDER BY area_easting ASC
            ");
            while ($row = pg_fetch_array($area_array)) {
                echo "<option>".$row['area_easting']." | ".$row['area_northing']."</option>";
                   }
        ?>          
        </select>

    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: $easting = $row['area_easting'] and the same for northing. Take care that you should use a different name for the variable for each iteration of the while

Comment: Where should they go in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED based on the comment by OP**

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($area_array)) {    
    $easting = $row['area_easting'];
    $northing = $row['area_northing'];    
    echo "<option value="$row['area_easting']|$row['area_northing']">$row['area_easting']|$row['area_northing']</option>";
}
```

this will give you the value of easting and northing and you can assign them on a variable after submitting the form. You were missing the value attribute of the options

Comment: I think i should rephrase, I only want the northing and easting of the selected option, this code returns the last value in my eastings or northings column. The while loop lists all coordinate pairs, but I want to access the easting and northing that are selected.